# p5.js says: There's an error due to "createVector" not being defined in the current scope

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using p5.js, and I am writing an Agar.io clone. But when I try to run the code, it says that:

> "p5.js says: There's an error due to "createVector" not being defined
> in the current scope."

Here is my code for sketch.js:

```
var blob;

var blobs = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob(width/2, height/2, 64);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    blobs[i] = new Blob(random(width), random(height), 16);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(blob.pos.x, blob.pos.y);
  blob.show();
  blob.update();

  for (var i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++) {
    blobs[i].show();
  }
}
```

And here's my code for blob.js:

```
function Blob(x, y, r) {
  this.pos = createVector(x, y);
  this.r = r;
    
  this.update = function() {
    var vel = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    vel.sub(this.pos);
    vel.setMag(3);
    this.pos.add(vel);
  }
    
    this.show = function() {
      fill(255);
      ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
    }
  }
```

The problem is, I also use the createVector function in other scripts, and it works fine in them. This is the only script where it doesn't work. Did I do something wrong? Please help!
Thank you

Comment: Is your `blob.js` file included **after** the `p5.js` file?

Comment: What do you mean after sketch.js?

Comment: @skully they mean in your index.html file

Comment: I went ahead and checked, yes, it is.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. It was just faulty index.html code. Thank you all for the help